# Is it ok to pronounce "might" as "my" when speaking fast in informal conversations?

Tags: pronunciation

I just realized whenever I pronounce the word "might" in the middle of a sentence in fast speech it sounds like "my" (e.g., I my do it), whereas I only really pronounce it as "mite" when it is at the end of a sentence or if I am being overly conscious about my pronunciation.

Does this happen to native speakers? Is it something that would be too obvious and grab your attention when hearing it? Does it make me sound like an idiot or something?

Comment: When does it come at the end? And when does it come in the middle? You might consider giving us some examples.

Comment: @Lambie At the end of a sentence is bc I commonly omit the verb when answering a question, so for instance "will you do it?", to which I answer "I might", or when it is not really at the end but I make a pause before continuing. In the middle of the phrase I reckon after reading the comments on Void's answer that I do pronounce mighta for "might have", in other cases idk, I feel like I may or may not pronounce it with the "glottal stop" the thing is the difference is too subtle for me to tell, but yeah, things like "I might be able" etc I believe sound like "I my be able" when I pronounce it.

Comment: "I might" usually has an hearable t. And I was the one who suggested mighta for might have gone, seen, done etc.

Comment: @Lambie, yeah, at the end of sentences is when I pronounce it as "mite".

Comment: For your information, all this comes under the heading of Connected Speech.

Answer (score 1):

Auxiliary verbs and modal auxiliaries are highly prone to elision/deletion and simplification. For example, very few people would pronounce the auxiliary *have* as [hæv] in colloquial speech; it's almost always pronounced [əv] (‘of’) that's why most people write ‘would have’ as ‘would of’ (i.e. they sound identical).

A considerable number of native speakers usually pronounce ‘might’ with a [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop) instead of a true ‘t’ at the end: [maɪʔ]. However, when it precedes a word starting with a ‘t’ or a ‘d’ then most native speakers merge the terminal consonant (glottal stop or /t/) with the following ‘t/d’ and prolong ‘t’. That's long ‘t’ is what's called a geminate ‘T’.

The t/d sounds are made by blocking the air completely at the ridge just above the top teeth and then releasing it. When you say ‘time’ you'll see that while articulating the ‘t’, the air is blocked at first and then released. In phrases like ‘I migh**t d**o/**t**ake...’, we have two adjacent T's and two releases are expected, but in colloquial speech, most speakers only have one release i.e. the first ‘t’ is unreleased and the second is fully released: might[**t̚t**ʰ]ake<sup>**1**</sup> ('might take'). (Gemination of plosives/stops has been explained [at Newcastle's University's website](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/geminates.htm)). In other words, the t is held a bit longer. Most people just put a glottal stop there, so *I might do it* might be pronounced **I migh[ʔ d]o it** ([ʔ] is a glottal stop).

**TL;DR** *I might do it* and *I my do it* are pronounced considerably differently in colloquial speech.

---

<sup>1. [t̚] is an [unreleased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release) ‘t’, meaning the blocked air is held and not released. [tʰ] on the other hand is released (and aspirated: the superscript h represents aspiration)</sup>

Comment: Often, might is migtha. I mighta done it.

Comment: @Lambie: What's the point that you're trying to make? Your comment makes no sense to me. 'Might' is never *mighta*, it's ‘might have' that's sometimes pronounced *mighta*.

Comment: You can write it phonetically. The word might is often pronounced might+ ah. In fast speech, **might have** becomes **mighta** and if that makes no sense, how            can you possibly answer this question?? Surely, you  know this, don't you?

Comment: ***I did not downvote your answer***. There is no downvote on your answer, as of this comment.  Of course, "might have" as in "might have done it" is spoken fast as: I mightah done it. I mightah gone. I mightah seen ya. Etc. etc. phonetic transcription: maɪta.

Comment: MIGHT HAVE
Don’t say, “might…have…been”. The contraction for might have is “might’ve”, and it usually sounds like, “mighta” when native speakers say it. https://gonaturalenglish.com/how-to-speak-english-fast-with-advanced-grammar/

Comment: @Lambie Clearly some people (perhaps the vast majority of speakers in North America) pronounce "might have" as "mighta", but I struggle to see the relevance of that to the OP's question, which is about whether people pronounce the /t/ - and the "t" is clearly present in "mighta", although it may well be voiced or flapped as "t"s often are in most American accents.  The OP's question isn't about how "might have" is pronounced - it's rather about whether the "t" goes missing in phrases like "I might do it".

Comment: @rjpond If you read the answer carefully, you will see I was just making a valid point in response to this: "The modal verb ‘might’ is usually pronounced with a glottal stop instead of a true ‘t’ at the end: [maɪʔ]". Isn't that a generalization? So, in terms of that **generalization**, my comment was on point **and** I might add pretty vanilla. The proper response would have been to acknowledge it and amend the answer. Then, I would have removed my comment. Is that to your liking?

Comment: @Lambie I see.  It is of course a generalisation (and the word "usually" was in there).  But I do not think that Void could have reasonably be expected to deduce what you were trying to say from "Often, might is migtha" or from your first four explanations of your comment. :)

Comment: @rjpond ***I wrote*** in my first comment: "**Often, might is migtha. I mighta done it**". That's plenty to deduce the usage. Please do not stir the pot anymore.

Comment: @Lambie: I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that you mentioned it I feel like I can't really tell if I pronounce it as "my" or if I do actually pronounce it with this "glottal stop", I think the difference is too subtle for me to hear it but I will try. I'll just wait a bit to see if anyone else has any takes on this before selecting the answer as final. Thank you.